# Count the number of instruction cycles of each instruction in the assembly generated for ARM

Tags: arm, instructions

How can i count the number of instruction cycles for each instruction in the assembly generated for a C/C++ program for ARM? Is there any tool for it? I don't want to look into ARM instruction set each time.

Answer (score 1):

Modern ARM systems doesn't specify cycles per instructions.

This is from [Cortex-A9 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.cortexa.a9/index.html)

> The complexity of the Cortex-A9 processor makes it impossible to
>   calculate precise timing information manually. The timing of an
>   instruction is often affected by other concurrent instructions, memory
>   system activity, and additional events outside the instruction flow.

However you can also look into [Cycle Counter for Cortex A8](http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php?lng=us).